# Creating MySQL Schema from AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Is it possible to create a MySQL Schema from a running AWS-based RDS database? I am a newbie and not sure whether there is a tool like what is available in MySQL workbench type dashboard to create schema at ease?

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to this but I recently created a MYSQL database on AWS RDS.
(I am new to MySQL and AWS).

The answer is yes, we can create schemas. However, as much as I understand, there is no concept of schema in MySQL. There is one database where you create the different database objects and then we just query those using one user or the other.
Edit:: Database and Schema are same thing as per the comments. So yes, we can create schemas and then users to access them.

Anyways, you can use the MySQL workbench to connect your AWS RDS database.
Or you can do the same using any coding language. For both the above options, make sure your database is created with 'Publicly accessible' option enabled.

Refer to this - https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-mysql-db/

If you follow all steps, your database on AWS should work like one installed locally on your machine.

Comment: MySQL has schemas. The terms `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE` are synonyms in MySQL syntax. Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html?

Comment: Apologies.. like I mentioned, I am new to MySQL. Editing my response accordingly.